# how to set mutiple columns as index in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following data:

```
            Adj Close  year  month  day    pc_day  
Date                                               
1989-01-03   1.164242  1989      1    3       NaN  
1989-01-04   1.211100  1989      1    4  0.333333  
1989-01-05   1.218310  1989      1    5  0.250000  
1989-01-06   1.229123  1989      1    6  0.200000  
1989-01-09   1.239936  1989      1    9  0.500000  
...               ...   ...    ...  ...       ...  
2007-12-24  24.785059  2007     12   24  0.142857  
2007-12-26  24.803761  2007     12   26  0.083333  
2007-12-27  24.756376  2007     12   27  0.038462  
2007-12-28  24.913471  2007     12   28  0.037037  
2007-12-31  24.695290  2007     12   31  0.107143  

[4790 rows x 10 columns]
```

For hierarchical indexing I have to set 2 columns as index, `Date` and `month`. Date is already an index in datetime but i want to add month to it.

For this i have added the following code:

```
data.set_index(['Date','month'], drop=False)
```

I got the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"
```

---

I had used `print(data.reset_index().set_index(['month','Date'], drop=False, inplace=True))` as advised by @null but the output is `none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). You only need [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with **`append=True`**:

```
data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)
```

or

```
data = data.set_index('month',append=True)
```

---

If you later need to swap the indices use: [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html):

```
data = data.set_index('month',append=True).swaplevel('Month','Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

As defined [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in the documentation. `set_index` method takes keys as an argument, where

> keys : label or array-like or list of labels/arrays
>   This parameter can be either a single column key, a single array of the same length as the calling DataFrame, or a list containing an arbitrary combination of column keys and arrays. Here, “array” encompasses Series, Index, np.ndarray, and instances of Iterator.

So it has to be a column name, or list of column names.

Just simply try:

```
data.reset_index().set_index(['Date', 'month'], drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The  output for was `none`

Comment: You don't need reset _index

Comment: @new coder if you use inplace=True. You don't need assign it again. Use: `data.set_index('month',append=True,inplace=True)` or `data = data.set_index('month',append=True)`

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I was not aware you could use append on set_index!

Comment: It is important to read carefully the information of each method. In the long run it saves time :) I hope you can consider accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your data,'Date', not set as an index

To set a multi-index dataframe for your data:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])

data.set_index(['Date', 'month'], inplace=True)
```

you should get

```
                Adj Close   year    day     pc_day
Date    month               
1989-01-03  1   1.164242    1989    3   0.000000
1989-01-04  1   1.211100    1989    4   0.333333
1989-01-05  1   1.218310    1989    5   0.250000
1989-01-06  1   1.229123    1989    6   0.200000
1989-01-09  1   1.239936    1989    9   0.500000
2007-12-24  12  24.785059   2007    24  0.142857
2007-12-26  12  24.803761   2007    26  0.083333
2007-12-27  12  24.756376   2007    27  0.038462
2007-12-28  12  24.913471   2007    28  0.037037
2007-12-31  12  24.695290   2007    31  0.107143
```

and the index shows as

```
data.index
```

should return

```
MultiIndex([('1989-01-03',  1),
        ('1989-01-04',  1),
        ('1989-01-05',  1),
        ('1989-01-06',  1),
        ('1989-01-09',  1),
        ('2007-12-24', 12),
        ('2007-12-26', 12),
        ('2007-12-27', 12),
        ('2007-12-28', 12),
        ('2007-12-31', 12)],
       names=['Date', 'month'])
```